# URL Parameters to PHP Variables

Tags: php, url, parameters, get

I've been doing PHP for a while now, never needed assistance, but totally confused this time. I have a single line of code with one echo statement.

Problem: URL parameters are automatically assuming PHP variable values of the same name. For example, I have a URL with a parameter named `var_name` like this:

```
http://www.example.com?var_name=abc123
```

and a 1-line PHP script with a variable named `var_name`, like this:

```
echo $var_name;
```

then I get output on the page of: `abc123`

This is the only code in the PHP page! This behavior is exactly how I expect `$_GET` to work, but I'm not using it.

I am having this problem only on 1 specific server, which is running PHP 5.2. I have tested on 4 other servers, none have this behavior. I assume it's a PHP config issue, but running default config and can't find anything in config documentation.

Answer (score 6):

This is called [register globals.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) If a server has register globals turned on, then you can do this.

I would recommend not to have register globals on any server. Since it can introduce a security flaw in your system.

An example of a security flaw with this.

```
if($auth == true)
{
    // sensitive stuff here
}
```

If auth is just a regular variable, then I can do this in the URL.

> http://www.example.com/page.php?auth=true

And see the sensitive information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Never used register_globals, never want to again. That's a gaping hole of vulnerability. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `register_globals` enabled:

See [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) for info.